# How to add my app to system wide context menu enabled when text is selected

Tags: android

I didn't find any documentation on how to my app to the context menu for providing my app's for the selected text.

Microsoft's Bing translator app provides this service.

This option can be found by selecting a text. You will get a context menu with copy, share, select all and ellipses option. On clicking ellipses, we get web search, assist, translate and translator (if Bing translator is installed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Android 6.0 and higher, you can [register an activity for `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/09/15/book-excerpt-floating-action-mode.html), to get included in such floating action menus.